# Iteratively Click and back to the main page but failed to go to the next page with Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have successfully used the following code to iteratively click through all the 25 records in the main page and print in the terminal the data I wanted to retrieve, and I also was able to flip through all the 40 pages with the second code. However, combining them ended up with the program always go back to the first page(a.k.a. the "main page" in the my earlier saying.) Any help would be highly appreciated!

The URL is as below:

```
# Invoke a new Chrome Instance
ff_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
# Blocking wait of 30 seconds in order to locate the element
ff_driver.implicitly_wait(30)
ff_driver.maximize_window()
 
# Open the Home Page
ff_driver.get("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2021")
```

The Iteratively clicking code:

```
for i in range(1, 25):

    buttons = ff_driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(f"#qs-rankings > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td.uni > div > a.more")
    
    for j in range(len(buttons)):
    
        ff_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", buttons[j])
        
        ff_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        results =  ff_driver.find_elements_by_class_name('criteria')

        for quote in results:
            quoteArr = quote.text.split('\n')
            print(quoteArr)
            print()
           
        ff_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            
        ff_driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Code for flipping through the 40 pages

```
for page in range(1, 40):   
    elements = ff_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qs-rankings_next"]')
    
    ff_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements)
    
    ff_driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

My code which failed to go to the next page

```
for page in range(1, 40):

    for i in range(1, 25):

        buttons = ff_driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(f"#qs-rankings > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td.uni > div > a.more")
   
        for j in range(len(buttons)):
    
            ff_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", buttons[j])
        
            ff_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
            results =  ff_driver.find_elements_by_class_name('criteria')

            for quote in results:
                quoteArr = quote.text.split('\n')
                print(quoteArr)
                print()
           
            ff_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            
            ff_driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

# click next page

    ff_driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    element = ff_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qs-rankings_next"]')
    
    ff_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
        
    ff_driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
    
ff_driver.close()
```

Comment: the "next" page button does not change the location bar.  (The DOM is updated via javascript)  So your back button will always go to the first page.  Page 2 is not saved in history...

Comment: what you could do instead is store the href's in an array.  So iterate through the pages, storing the hrefs of the links.  Then after you've gone through all the pages, iterate through your stored hrefs, using driver.get()s and grab your quotes.

Comment: Thanks!! Because if simply flipping pages it worked. I did not imagine this might have been the case. Q__Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same behavior manually (if we click back we return to main page) so it's not a problem of combining of your code.

You can do somithing like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ff_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
ff_driver.maximize_window()
ff_driver.get("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2021")
btn_more = "#qs-rankings a.more"

links = []
for page in range(40):
    WebDriverWait(ff_driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, btn_more)))
    buttons = ff_driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(btn_more)

    for button in buttons:
        links.append(button.get_attribute("href"))

    elements = WebDriverWait(ff_driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "qs-rankings_next")))
    ff_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements)

for link in links:
    ff_driver.get(link)
    WebDriverWait(ff_driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'criteria')))
    results = ff_driver.find_elements_by_class_name('criteria')

    for quote in results:
        quoteArr = quote.text.split('\n')
        print(quoteArr)
        print()
```

P.S. I used explicit waits instead of implicit :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have spent days and its mixed feeling to see the answer lol